# Filtering polygons by long/lat values using sf package in R?

Tags: r, sf

Suppose `t` is:

```
t <- structure(list(structure(list(structure(c(-89.990791, -89.990772, 
-89.990901, -89.99092, -89.990791, 30.727025, 30.727083, 30.727114, 
30.727057, 30.727025), .Dim = c(5L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", 
"sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(-89.991691, -89.991755, -89.991755, 
-89.991691, -89.991691, 30.716004, 30.716004, 30.715916, 30.715916, 
30.716004), .Dim = c(5L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg"
))), class = c("sfc_POLYGON", "sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = -89.991755, 
ymin = 30.715916, xmax = -89.990772, ymax = 30.727114), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(
    epsg = 4326L, proj4string = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L)
> t
Geometry set for 2 features 
geometry type:  POLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: -89.99176 ymin: 30.71592 xmax: -89.99077 ymax: 30.72711
epsg (SRID):    4326
proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
POLYGON ((-89.99079 30.72703, -89.99077 30.7270...
POLYGON ((-89.99169 30.716, -89.99175 30.716, -...
```

How can I filter polygons by long/lat boundaries? Suppose I want to filter out any polygon that hax lat>30.72 (so to keep only the second polygon). Is there any specific function I can use to filter polygons?

Comment: As an aside, do not use R base functions as object names. You should always check as this can cause some very unexpected behavior, especially in functions. The "t" object is named the same as the transpose base function. To check object/function names conflicts just type the object name before you create the object. If a "Error: object 'x' not found" error is returned then it is safe.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution using `dplyr`:

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

good_polys <- data.frame(st_coordinates(t)) %>%
  group_by(L2) %>%
  mutate(max_y = Y > 30.72) %>%
  distinct(L2, max_y)

t[good_polys$max_y]
```

Answer (score 0):

another solution that deals better with floating number

```r
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

polys_coords <- lapply(t, st_coordinates)
id_good_polys <- sapply(polys_coords, function(poly) !all(poly[,"Y"] >= 30.72))
good_polys <- t[id_good_polys]
```